# Is it shirk to say Jesus lord

Tags: allah

One day on accident I said to my friends ‘oh Jesus lord’ it came out by accident. This happened almost a year now I asked Allan for forgiveness and forgot about it. Now it’s ramadan and I have been thinking about sins that have done throughout my life. I feel like have committed shirk . But I do  believe in Allaah and the prophets (pbut) I believe that there is only one god (Allah)

Answer (score 2):

No it is not considered shirk if it is said accedently. The prophet said:

> *Verily Allah has pardoned [or been lenient with] for me my ummah: their mistakes, their forgetfulness, and that which they have been forced to do under duress*
>   [40.39](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/39)

So if it came out by mistake, Allah will forgive you Inshallah.

However, It is considered shirk if one says it intentionally as Allah says:

> *Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills.*
>   [4:116](https://quran.com/4/116)

Answer (score 0):

Although Ahmad Taher provided an excellent answer to the question, let me answer it from another point of view. I think it also matters how, why and in which meanings you have used the word "lord". For example, Cambridge English Dictionary defines the word "lord" as:

"a man who has a lot of power in a particular area of activity".

"to behave as if you are better than someone and have the right to tell them what to do: "

"in the UK, used to address a judge or peer"

"a title used in front of the names of male peers and officials of very high rank:"

For details see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lord

I do not think in any of the above mentioned meanings it is regarded as shirk.

Jesus is lord of Muslims as well in the sense that he is a prophet, a man of very high rank.